# for loop ends unexpected in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a html button that calls this function. But for unknown reason it only goes 3 iterations.

Can anyone help or refer me to some good example why the for loop breaks after the third iteration?

```
for(i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
   alert(i);
  if (document.getElementById(i).checked) {
    alert("dda3");
    act = act + document.getElementById("TD" + i).innerHTML + delimiter;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you put your html code part?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the javascript console?

Comment: Seems to work fine - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/quA4V/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you dont have an element with that ID and thats why it breaks the for loop , go try in the html part of your code where you initialize the names of the  where you don't increment or decrement  if you do it correctly ( in while of for or foreach loop) maybe you are using the same $i variable for 2 different loops or changing its value (other than $i++ or $i--)

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason is that you don't have an element with the `id` value `"4"`. Consequently, `document.getElementById` returns `null`, and then when you try to look at the `checked` attribute, you're dereferencing a `null`, which throws an exception. Or of course, you don't have an element with the `id` value `"TD4"` and so your later `getElementById` returns `null` and you get the exception when assigning to `innerHTML`.

When trying to debug things, it's best to use a debugger. All modern browsers have debuggers built in — and some of them are quite good. On most browsers, pressing F12 will bring up the debugger, but if not go looking through the menus for "developer tools" or similar.

Even if there's no debugger, all browsers going back more than a decade have a means of telling you about JavaScript errors. I would at the very least enable that so you can see errors.

---

Side note: `id` values starting with digits are only recently allowed in HTML (valid in HTML5, not valid in HTML4 or earlier) and are still not valid in CSS. I recommend avoiding them.